# Click event happens during a lot of frames

Tags: javascript, canvas

The Javascript click event is added to a lot of frames in my app.
I need the click event to happen only once, not 200 frames. The frames seem to stack each other, adding even more frames for each click.
How can I make it so that it only happens once?

Here is the event code:

```
    function a(e){
        var x = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

        if(x >= initialScreen.x && x <= initialScreen.x + initialScreen.width
            && y >= initialScreen.y && y <= initialScreen.y + initialScreen.height){
            ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click',a,false);
            quit = true;
        }
        else if(x >= left.x && x <= left.x + left.width 
            && y >= left.y && y <= left.y + left.height){
            ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', a, false);
            player.x += 5;
        }
    }

    // Add the click event using the previous function
    ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', a, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to indicate if the canvas is already wired to listen for clicks

```
var isListeningToClick;
```

Then use that flag to only switch listening on/off once:

```
function a(e){
    var x = e.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

    if(x >= initialScreen.x && x <= initialScreen.x + initialScreen.width
        && y >= initialScreen.y && y <= initialScreen.y + initialScreen.height){
        if(isListeningToClick){
            ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click',a,false);
            isListeningToClick=false;
        }
        quit = true;
    }
    else if(x >= left.x && x <= left.x + left.width 
        && y >= left.y && y <= left.y + left.height){
        if(!isListeningToClick){
            ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', a, false);
            isListeningToClick=true;
        }
        player.x += 5;
    }
}

// Add the click event using the previous function
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', a, false);
isListeningToClick=true;
```